# Count numbers deleted by removing consecutive digit pairs that don't sum to 17

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Below is the problem statement that I have:

You get number written in base 10, you have to delete it completely by choosing two consecutive digits and deleting them. But the sum of those 2 digits should not be 17.  We call the numbers which are fully deleted by repeating the above operation as **"Good"**.

Example:

1. `9889` => Delete `88` to get `99`
2. `99` => Delete `99` to fully delete number.
   Conclusion: 9889 is **good**.
   NOTE: We cannot remove `98` or `89` as the sum of these 2 digits is `17`.

Given a number N(even) you want to find the number of **good** N-digit number modulo `10^9 + 7`. Include in the count the N digit numbers containing leading zeros, too.

**Test Cases:**

Case 1:

```
Input: 2
Output: 98
```

Case 2:

```
Input: 4
Output: 9926
```

Case 3:

```
Input: 442
Output: 417551213
```

I have tried solving this using various codes but not able to get the result.

Comment: Just as a side note, 99 is not formed from two consecutive digits of 9889.  The consecutive digits of 9889 are 98, 88 or 89.

Comment: First we remove 88 from 9889, so the number becomes 99. Now 99 are consecutive digits.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see now.  :D

Comment: No offence but it has no practical use. How can I flag it for that? :D Just Kidding

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: Am I getting this wrong, that `Output: 417551213` should be reduced further? there is `55` that can be removed..

Comment: Some more test cases I generated: `N=6`: `997460` and `N=8`: `99913670`. An observation I noticed is that all _"bad"_ numbers directly contain `89` _or_ `98` in the starting number (however the inverse is _not_ true; a number may contain these and be _"good"_).

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri- No the output will not be getting reduced. So the question is like how many 442 digit numbers are present which can be considered as good. So the answer to that is `Output: 417551213`. These many 442 digit numbers are present which can be considered as good.

Comment: There are that many 442 digit numbers that are considered _good_, ***modulo*** `10^9 + 7`, hence 417551213. The actual number would likely have 441 digits. The proportion of good numbers seems to asymptotically tend towards 1 (i.e. 100%) as `N` grows.

Comment: can you show the code you tried

Comment: Is this a kata from Codewars (https://www.codewars.com) or a problem from Project Euler (https://projecteuler.net/) or similar? If yes, can you please provide a link to the source?

Comment: @concision you may be interested in my answer with working code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each sequence of the last possible bad state, there must have been a forced sequence that generated it. Look at the locations of possible wild-cards (the digits that offer choice are the ones of interest, of course), and try to find a pattern.

In the following examples, for symmetry, switch 9s with 8s; `x`s are wildcards:

Input length 4, bad result 9898:

```
9898
```

Input length 4, bad result 98:

```
989x
98x8
9x98
x898
```

We can clearly see from the two above why we get the output, 9926 good 4-digit numbers.

Input length 6, bad result 9898:

```
98989x
9898x8
989x98
98x898
9x9898
x89898
```

Input length 6, bad result 9898 OR 98:

```
9898xx
989xx8
98xx98
9xx898
xx9898
```

Input length 6, bad result 98:

```
989x9x
98x8x8
...
9x989x
...
```

etc.

Python code:

```py
# https://gist.github.com/rougier/ebe734dcc6f4ff450abf
def binom(n,k):
  if not 0<=k<=n: return 0
  b=1
  for t in range(min(k,n-k)):
    b*=n; b//=t+1; n-=1
  return b

def f(n):
  bads = 0
  
  for k in range((n - 2) // 2 + 1):
    bads += 9**k * binom(n, k)
  
  return (10**n - 2 * bads) % (10**9 + 7) 
  
print(f(442)) # 417551213
```

Comment: Nice ! Is this a known problem ? 
Would you mind explaining this sentence "We can clearly see from the two above why we get the output, 9926 good 4-digit numbers" ? It is not obvious to me as it is

Comment: @Youri I don't know if it's known, this is the first I've seen it. `9898` is 1 bad; and for each of `989x, 98x8, 9x98, x898`, we get 9 ways, replacing the `x` with a digit that can join its neighbours. That's 1 + 4*9 = 37 bad ones. Due to symmetry, switching 8s with 9s, we double that and get 74 bad ones. 10000 - 74 = 9926 (we use 10000 for the total good and bad numbers because we include numbers with leading zeros).

Comment: Silly me, that does sound obvious now, I was lacking one step in my thinking, thanks for the explanation !

Answer (score 1):

Try with using a tree to try every possible solution. The real problem is that, you have to predict what digit will stay and if you can delete them without having a sum of 17.
For exemple, if you have 9823 you can delete 23 but you'll be blocked with 98 at the end.

You can try building a tree with every branch being a possibility of deletion. If all of the branches are blocked you get back to the previous node

Comment: I haven't worked with trees earlier, and the solution is supposed to be inside O(N^2). I guess the solution you suggest will take more time. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Amiral has a good point, unless you figure out some smart arithmetic/calculus trick with number, you'll have to use backtracking, and a tree.. so you can look into the N-queens problem for starters, it is a good example !

Answer (score 0):

Not wanting to spoil the coding, but whether a number is good, could be done with *backtracking*.

```
    solve(9889);

public static void solve(int num) {
    try {
        solve(num, new LinkedList<>());
        System.out.println("Not found");
    } catch (FoundException fe) {
        System.out.printf("%d%n", num);
        fe.result.forEach(pair -> System.out.printf("-> %d, having deleted %d%n",
            pair.getKey(), pair.getValue()));
    }
}

private static class FoundException extends RuntimeException {
    public final List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> result;

    public FoundException(List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}

private static void solve(int num, LinkedList<Pair<Integer, Integer>> partialResult) {
    if (num == 0) {
        throw new FoundException(partialResult);
    }
    int tenPower = 1;
    while (num >= tenPower) {
        int n = num / tenPower;
        int del = n % 100;
        if (del % 10 + del / 10 != 17) {
            int n2 = (n / 100) * tenPower + (num % tenPower);
            partialResult.addLast(new Pair<>(n2, del));
            solve(n2, partialResult);
            partialResult.removeLast();
        }
        tenPower *= 10;
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be formulated such that an `int` (31 bits unsigned int) suffices.
Hence I tried working with `int` instead of a list of digits.

An other feature: using an exception to return from deep inside recursion to the top level with a positive result. The traditional way would be to check the result of a recursive call.

**Note: the actual problem is a more mathematical one.**

Comment: @גלעדברקן That is indeed better readable (removing xx). Because of the java tag and this proably being a task, I just wanted to break any mental programming block. And technicalities such as being able to use a primitive int, and perhaps even an exception with stack unwinding.